# Flutter Android Studio cursor flashing issue. Can't enter text

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Sometimes my cursor starts flashing and I can't modify text. Very annoying thing and I don't know what to do. I enter a text from a keyboard but it us just flashing.

[image]

Comment: Press the `0` key of the numpad.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Go to File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance, then uncheck the Use 
 block caret
```

or Remove these directories:

~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta

Answer (score 0):

Disable IdeaVim plug-in in the IDE Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Plugins.

Comment: thanks! looks like a solution I will reply when test this well